# Limit the frequency shown on histogram

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, histogram

I am using matplotlib to plot a histogram and I have the following code:

```
plt.hist(data["Main Total"],alpha=.7)
plt.title("Total marks Histogram")
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.show()
```

This produces a histogram as follows:
[image]

but when I add `histtype=stepfilled` as follows

```
plt.hist(data["Main Total"],histtype="stepfilled", alpha=.7)
```

It produces:
[image]

When using `stepfilled` why is that the frequency maximum that is shown in the graph a very high value even though there is no data having frequency higher than 20 unlike the first histogram which shows it properly.

Here is the code with which you can recreate the issue

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import statsmodels.api as sm
from numpy.random import randn
import matplotlib as mpl
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_color_palette("deep", desat=.6)
mpl.rc("figure", figsize=(8, 4))

data=pd.read_csv("output11cs.csv")
df3=data[['Total','Total.1','Total.2','Total.3','Total.4','Total.5','Total.6','Total.7']]
data["Main Total"]=df3.sum(axis=1)
data = data.dropna()
data.reset_index(drop=True)
plt.hist(data["Main Total"],alpha=.7)
plt.title("Total marks Histogram")
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.show()
```

Here is [output11cs.csv file](http://pastebin.com/er56H2DZ). It has just `90` lines

Comment: what version of mpl are you using?

Comment: can you reproduce this on 1.3.1 or master?  It looks like more issues with the auto-scaler...

Comment: And can you post an example with fake-data that will reproduce this?

Comment: @tcaswell Updated with the code and data I am trying to run

Comment: I can confirm that the code you shared works as expected (after changing the `reset_index` line to overwrite `data`) on Matplotlib 1.3.1. I think I remember there were some issues with histogram scaling on 1.2, as well.

Comment: What if you manually set the plt.ylim(18) ?

Comment: @CarolineAlexiou my data can change and it is not always below 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my comment above, I think this will work fine if you upgrade matplotlib to 1.3.x, but in case you're on a system where upgrading is not possible, you can also change the "linewidth" of the histogram to get the same effect:

```
plt.hist(data["Main Total"], alpha=.7, linewidth=0)
plt.title("Total marks Histogram")
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Frequency");
```

[image]

Comment: `linewidth=0` did work but I will also try upgrading and see what happens